# The closure of the set of injective continuous functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, differential-topology

**Setup/Notation:**
Let $n,m\in \mathbb{N}$ and let $C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ be the space of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ equipped with the compact-open topology.  Let $\mathcal{I}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ be the subset of $C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ consisting of injective functions.

*Observations - Effect of Dimension:*

- If $n\leq m$: The subset $\mathcal{I}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ need not be closed.  To see this note that the family
  $$
  f_{n}(x):=\frac1{n}\cdot x,
  $$
  converges to $0$ (in the compact-open topology).
- If $n>m$: Then [Brouwer's Invariance Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) implies that $\mathcal{I}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)=\emptyset$.  In particular, $\overline{\mathcal{I}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)}=\emptyset\neq C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$.

---

**Question:**  Is there a critical $m^{\star}$ (depending on $n$) such that if:
$$
\begin{cases}
\overline{\mathcal{I}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)}
 =
C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m) &: m\geq m^{\star}\\
\overline{\mathcal{I}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)}
 \neq
C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m) & : m<m^{\star}
\end{cases}?
$$
If so, more precisely, what is $m^{\star}$ and how does it depend on $n$?

---

**Partial Thoughts/Observations''** - *(Edit)*: If we embed $C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$ into $C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^{m+n})$ via $f\mapsto \tilde{f}_{\infty}(x):=[x\mapsto (f(x),0)]$ then, for any $f\in C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^{m})$ we can define the maps:
$$
\tilde{f}_{n}(x):= (f(x),\frac1{n}\cdot x).
$$
Moreover, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, the map $f\mapsto \tilde{f}_n$ is an embedding.  So, then in this way... an affirmative pseudo-answer to the question below is ``kind of'' since:
$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\,\tilde{f}_n =\tilde{f}_{\infty}$ and each $\tilde{f}_n \in \mathcal{I}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^{m+n})$ and is the image of some $C(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^m)$.

Comment: I doubt that $\mathcal I(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$ is ever dense in $C(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$. For $n=1$ this should follow from the fact that every component of a continuous injective function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^m$ is strictly monotone.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth I don't follow. If a curve is injective, its components need not to be injective.

Comment: @PietroMajer Ah true, for example $f_1\in C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is any strictly monotone increasing function.  Then, for any $f_2\in C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$, the map $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x))$ is  injective *(even if $f_2$ need not be)*.  **Takeaway**: I it's sufficient for one component of a map $f\in C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}^m)$ to be monotonically increasing but the injectivity of $f$ does not imply that all its components to be monotone).

Comment: But note that  a curve $\mathbb R\to\mathbb{R^2}$, whose image has a self-crossing point, can't be approximated by injective curves

Comment: @PietroMajer Why is this?

Comment: @PietroMajer oops..., I don't follow either.

Comment: just consider a nbd of the crossing point; say that there the curve to be approximated looks like this $\otimes$. Any approximating curve has to follow the two segments, and needs to cross itself.

Comment: @PietroMajer Does it though, or (if there are enough dimensions) can it look like $\otimes$ but it $\epsilon$-comes close to crossing itself at that point.

Comment: I'd say there is the same obstruction  if $n\ge m/2$: there is a smooth map with say $f(a)=f(b)=0$ and $df(a)\pitchfork df(b)$. Say the images of the differentials are two linear spaces whose sum is the whole space. Then  I think any close enough continuous approximation of $f$  has a self-intersection too, by topological degree reasons.

Comment: @TomTheQuant: Sure, in 3 or more dimensions you can make it injective, but the point is not in 2.

Comment: If n<m/2 one can first approximate the map by a smooth one, and then try to approximate by injective ones. There should be enough room.

Comment: In fact if n<m/2 I think by Sard's theorem one can make all self intersections transverse, which means no self-intersections

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kuratowski proved in [Sur les théorèmes du „plongement" dans la théorie de la dimension. *Fundamenta Mathematicae* 28.1 (1937): 336-342](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm28/fm28137.pdf) that the set of embeddings of an at most $n$-dimensional separable metrizable space into $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ contains a dense $G_\delta$-set.
Hence $m^*\le 2m+1$.

Comment: Thanks this is very interesting and basically exactly what I had hoped for! :)

Comment: A more tentative argument for the inequality $m^*\ge2m+1$: the union of all $n$-dimensional faces of a $2n$-simplex cannot be embedded in to $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (Flores, 1935, see Exercise 1.11.H in Engelkings *Theory of Dimensions. Finite and Infinite*). In case $n=1$ you get the complete graph $K_5$. If you draw that in the plane as a pentagram in a circle and if you parametrize that, say with a map of period $10$ then no map close enough to that parametrization is injective (hence $1^*\ge3$). I would expect that something similar can be done for larger $n$.